# How to implement lazy scrolling with Single Child Scroll View

Tags: flutter

I know List view builder is the implementation of lazy scrolling, and its working fine for Cases i show just the list view but what if i have a page that is Built by couple of list view and i warp the page with Single Child Scroll View.
How can i implement the same effect for this case.
Like my page will be on top: an list view builder with scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
than a littler static data and on the bottom new list view builder vertical, that list view builder lazy loading wont work because physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics().
So to sum up there is a way implement that lazy scroling or i must implement paging when scroll down.

Example:

```
   DrawerListHeader(
      text: "Popular Leagues",
      leftPadding: leftPadding,
      icon: Container(
        height: iconSize,
        width: iconSize,
        child: SvgPicture.asset(AppIcons.cupGreen),
      ),
    ),
    ListView.builder(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: _favoriteLeagues.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return LeagueRow(
            rowHeight: rowHeight,
            leftPadding: leftPadding,
            name: _favoriteLeagues[index].name,
            logoPath: _favoriteLeagues[index].logoPath,
            iconSize: iconSize,
          );
        }),
    DrawerListHeader(
      text: "Countries",
      leftPadding: leftPadding,
      icon: SvgPicture.asset(AppIcons.countriesGreen),
    ),
    ListView.builder(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: _countries.length,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ExpandableListView(
          country: _countries[index],
          leftPadding: leftPadding,
          rowHeight: rowHeight - 5,
          isClose: isClose,
          iconSize: iconSize,
        );
      },
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding [Slivers](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/slivers) are the good option for this kind of advance UI patterns.

[One of the great article](https://medium.com/flutter/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f) for better sliver understanding and usage.

Comment: i see Custom Scroll View can have just silver list and silver grid so is it like getting all my page widgets into an List and using list view builder no?